# Manhwa/manhua where a fox/demon bothers and stays with the male lead

Tags: story-identification, manga

As this is my first question I have tried to search it on Google and the site but  didn't find it. It is a fully colored and the characters are described below (to the best of my memory). Also, the question is quite long. Sorry for that.

**As I don't know the title** *(hence, the `story-identification tag`)*, and I am a bit unsure about the entire story, I have *really* tried to **be as specific as I can**, as the [how-to-ask](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) article tells me to.

First of all, **what have I tried?**

##### This site and Searching the net

I have tried looking for it by Google searching with the following terms:

- Looking for a manhwa/manhua where a fox...
- Looking for a manhwa where a fox...

But no relevant results come up.

##### Online tools

I have tried to use (numerous) tools online, to identify images, such as Bing's "similar images to these" and other tools. I have even tried to see if some metadata is kept to try to identify anything of that (of the pictures, for the possibility that one of the screenshots maybe isn't a screenshot) but no luck there.

#### Description of The Manhwa(or Manhua)

It is colored. and It is translated in English.
I really do not think it is a manga per say, which is why I say "manhwa/manhua."

#### Characters

Main character (MC), male lead (ML), a red-haired character, a white-haired character, and a black-white fox:

- The MC I remember had long brown hair. And was told off to be married to a mysterious prince (to the ML)
- The ML had black long hair.
- The red-haired character removes the curse that ML has
- The white-haired character is a like fox demon that bothers and stays with ML
- The red-haired character is the white-haired character's sister
  (she’s the older sibling, I think)

And the black and white fox doesn’t talk.

There are some demon-related things in the story as well.

#### Where did I read it?

I am pretty certain that I read it on **Manganato**.

#### Screenshots

I have two screenshots of the manhwa/manhua (as I can't really remember it all, this is another thing I try to post in order to make it a more specific and useful post).

---

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

### Last words

As this is my first question, there is a lot to check (correctness, broadness, etc.) which I have tried my best to do properly. But if something is unclear, please point it out! I will try to respond as quickly as possible.

Wishes from Sweden! Thanks, and have a great day!

---

edit: *it's a friend that asked me a couple of days, and I tried to find it but couldn't. thanks for the answer(s)!  `:)` I salute from Sweden to this site as thanks for the help!*

---

Comment: I may not be well versed into the acronyms, so what is _ML_?

Comment: @Clockwork oh! no worries, ML = Male Lead (same as FL = Female Lead)  and MC (Main Character) I will add these to my question.  **Thank you for asking!**

Comment: Strange, why is the edit history saying I changed so many things when I merely re-added the notes at the end of the question? Quite funny what's happening there.

Comment: @Clockwork Because you did change a bunch of things that didn't need changing.  Besides you don't put a legend at the end where it's no use to the people who have already given up; you expand all the abbreviations throughout the post.

Comment: @DavidW I'm adamant I did not change the other things though. Strangely enough, right when I clicked on save, the page told me another edit had just happened. Still, I will take into account your feedback for future edits though. Thanks. Edit: I think my browser still had a cache of the first version of the post, before the second edit happened (most likely because I used the back button).

Comment: SORRY to BOTH of you!   It was me who added the "*terminology*' list, and that edit probably caused some, problem. My deepest apologies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be [*An Inescapable Love*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/an-inescapable-love).  The summary:

> For Princess Seollan, life as the twin sister and shadow of the sickly crown prince was a suffocating prison. So when the king commands her to marry Jihwan of House Choi, she knows it's her only chance to escape the palace and its shackles. Unfortunately, poor Jihwan was cursed by a vengeful white fox with a dangerous thirst for royal blood, and is dead set against their marriage. But in the end, the two are powerless to stop the wedding. Thus, Seollan is determined to find a cure for her new husband-- but the truth that they uncover may be more cruel than the curse itself. Will their newfound love bloom bright in the snow, despite the harsh winds of fate that lie ahead?

The second image you posted appears to be from chapter 19:

[image: Seollan speaks with a nine-tailed fox in human form, while a young boy holds his bleeding nose]

Comment: Thanks!  the friend that asked me for help(Yes it was a friend actually) (will add this to the question as well) told me it was the correct one! thanks a lot!  he/she became very happy and have a great day!

Comment: can I just ask, how did you find this?? I tried nearly every tool online and couldn't find it (if you didn't just "know it" ofc)  and it's mostly a curiosity question, really. Have a great day!

Comment: It is okay if you do not know ofc, I was just Curious;  please - Saluting from Sweden!   and **thanks** once more

Comment: @WilliamMartens Hey, sorry for being slow responding; actually Google image search got me most of the way there.

Comment: thanks!! no worries really; thanks a lot ! holy !  ; good work!